# How to filter data between two dates in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to develop a blood donation app. Here I need to get the donor's data which have last donated date more than 6 months ago that is if the donor has donated in last six months the donor's data should not be rendered to the template. I am trying to do that but could not figured out to do. So if anyone can help me then thank you in advance.
Here is a column in `models.py`

```
lastDonatedDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I just need to filter the donor's detail from the current date and the difference between two dates should be greater than 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`__range`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    lastDonateDate__range=('2021-01-01', '2021-03-01')
)
```

or if we want to filter six months ago, we can install the [**`dateutil`** package [readthedocs]](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with:

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
```

and then filter with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

MyModel.objects.filter(
    lastDonateDate__lt=now()-relativedelta(months=6)
)
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `last_donated_date` instead of <s>`lastDonatedDate`</s>.

Comment: the date should be filtered dynamically.

Comment: Ok i got that, I was unknown about that.

Comment: @PrasiddhaPokhrel: then you simply replace the string with a `date`(`time` object), for example for six months ago, see edit.

Comment: Actually i need to filter when rendering donor's data in ListView in .html file, according to you it is filtering when registering the donor. Could you suggest another idea.

Comment: @PrasiddhaPokhrel: no, why would that be filtered when registering the donor? You simply override `get_queryset` in the `ListView` to retrieve the filtered queryset.

Comment: Ok i will try that, Thank you.